# Cannot start Subgit synchronisation automatically within Gitlab Docker Container via runit

Tags: docker, gitlab, subgit, runit

My local Gitlab CE Docker container has Subgit included. When the Gitlab container is restarted the Subgit synchronisation should also start automatically.

My solution is derived from the original [Dockerfile](https://hub.docker.com/r/gitlab/gitlab-ce/~/dockerfile/) of gitlab/gitlab-ce on Dockerhub. In the original Dockerfile an SSH daemon has been added and set under control of runit.

I did the same with Subgit. Under **/opt/gitlab/sv/subgit** are my runit resources and subgit is enabled by setting a soft link to the **/opt/gitlab/service** directory. But when Gitlab Container is started the soft link is removed and therefore runsvdir is ignoring my Subgit runit files. When the soft link is enabled manually runsvdir is starting Subgit synchronisation successfully.

How can I persist the soft link and keep the automatic start of Subgit enabled respectively?

---

Here is the part of the Dockerfile regarding Subgit and runit:

```
RUN mkdir -p /opt/gitlab/sv/subgit/supervise && \
mkfifo /opt/gitlab/sv/subgit/supervise/ok && \
ln -s /opt/gitlab/sv/subgit /opt/gitlab/service/subgit
COPY ./runit_subgit_run /opt/gitlab/sv/subgit/run
COPY ./runit_subgit_finish /opt/gitlab/sv/subgit/finish
RUN chmod a+x /opt/gitlab/sv/subgit/run /opt/gitlab/sv/subgit/finish
```

And this is the run file for runit. The real Gitlab group and project names are replaced.

```
#!/bin/sh

exec 2>&1

exec /bin/sh -c "( subgit install \
"/var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories/<group_1>/<project_1>.git" && \
subgit install \
"/var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories/<group_2>/<project_1>.git" && \
subgit register \
"/var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories/<group_1>/<project_1>.git" && \
subgit register \
"/var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories/<group_2>/<project_1>.git" )"
```